# How may I convert Matlab code into Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I tried to convert Matlab code to Python but in this `xx = diff(xx>setpoint);` situation I did not get the same result in python.

```matlab
fs = 50;
t = [0:1/fs:1];
xx = sin(2*pi*300*t)+2*sin(2*pi*600*t);

xx = xx(:)'/max(abs(xx));   %-- normalize xx
Lx = length(xx);
Lz = round(0.01*fs);
setpoint = 0.02;      
%xx = filter( ones(1,Lz)/Lz, 1, abs(xx) );
xx = diff(xx>setpoint);
```

Actually I don't understand what the statement `xx = diff(xx>setpoint)` do.

Comment: You are stating that your python code behaves different, please add your python code to your question.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Python is different, you can make Python like Matlab, in this case I prefer the approach of Python.

---

In Python `xx>0.002` is an array of Booleans, `False`  and `True` and `np.diff` treats the Boolean values as such, in Matlab `xx>0.002` is a matrix of logical values as well but `diff` converts them to `0` and `1` before taking the differences and this imply that we have more possibilities in Matlab

```
In [15]: for a, b in ((0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)): print(np.diff((a,b)))                  
[0]
[1]
[-1]
[0]

In [16]: f, t = False, True 
    ...: for a, b in ((f,f), (f,t), (t,f), (t,t)): print(np.diff((a,b)))                  
[False]
[ True]
[ True]
[False]
```

When  I plot `xx` and `diff(xx>0.02)` in Matlab (oh well, in Octave...) I have

[image]

When I plot `xx` and `np.diff(xx>0.02)` in Python+Numpy+Matplotlib I get

[image]

To have *exactly* the results of Matlab we can convert the boolean array to an array of floats, just multiplying by `1.0` is OK — so this is the plot of `xx` and `np.diff( 1.0*(xx>0.02) )`

[image]

If the aim of the OP is to show where the signal is larger than `0.02` I dare say that the native Python (no conversion to floats) is better at that...

Comment: Your explanation about MATLAB is slightly off, `xx>0.002` is of data type logical, but the result of `false-true` is a double of value -1.

Comment: @Daniel I'll correct the answer, thank you for the correction.